Reading Secret from Google secret manager and pass as environment variable in Pod
I am storing secrets in google cloud secret manager in JSON format and need to read each key and pass the value as environment variable. I have refered various blogs but not able to do so. In AWS, I was able to do it using JMESPATH, it would be great if some one could help me to achieve the same.
{
"value-A": "abscd"
"value-B": "sdskdf"
}

I need to Need Value-A and pass as environment variable. Similary Value-B as environment variable in the pod. so  I could read the values using ${value-A} and ${value-B}

I highly doubt that's possible, I also don't see why you would want to do this, you have 2 much more maintainable options already:

Store value-A and value-B in different secret fields
Store the whole thing as a single json string in a secret and parse them with a json lib at runtime


Could you help me how can i achieve option 2. I am bit new to GCP

I tried to replicate using your access secret data in a Pod by combining through a Volume and container environment variables which gives the desired values that you needed.
Here are the steps:

Create and apply a secret in JSON format as my-secret.json:

{ 
"value-A": "abscd" 
,"value-B": "sdskdf" 
}


Create and apply pod with this configuration:

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: secret-test-pod
spec:
 containers:
   - name: test-container
     image: nginx
     volumeMounts:
       # Mount the secret as a volume
       - name: secret-volume
         mountPath: /etc/secret-volume
         readOnly: true
     envFrom:
       # Inject the secret as environment variables
       - secretRef:
           name: my-secret
 volumes:
   - name: secret-volume
     secret:
       secretName: my-secret


Get a shell into the Container that is running in your Pod:

kubectl exec -i -t secret-test-pod(metadata_name) -- /bin/bash


In your shell, display the contents of the value-A and value-B from JSON file:

# Run this in the shell inside the container
echo "$( cat /etc/secret-volume(volumes name)/value-A )"
echo "$( cat /etc/secret-volume(volumes name)/value-B )"


The output is your values-A & values-B only.

For alternative approaches, use the Secret Manager add-on for GKE.
